# Static void метод и переменная

Tags: c#

Есть простое консольное приложение, в котором написан рекурсивный метод. В общем это выглядит так

```
namespace somenamespace
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Recursive(...)
    }

    static void Recursie(...)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Соответственно метод ссылается сам на себя и во время его работы мне нужна переменная которая бы сохраняла какое то значение связанное с этим методом. Допустим в одной ветке цикла в методе я ее увеличиваю, в другой уменьшаю и использую во время работы метода. Как поступить в таком случае?

Почему если объявить этот метод без static, программа требует экземпляр? Как сделать этот экземпляр?Если через `new Program()`, то что будет с `void Main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Соответственно метод ссылается сам на себя и во время его работы мне нужна переменная которая бы сохраняла какое то значение связанное с этим методом.

Добавьте статическое поле и работайте с ним:

```
namespace somenamespace
{
  class Program
  {
    private static int value = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Recursive(...)
    }

    static void Recursive(...)
    {
        value++;
    }
  }
}
```

> Почему если объявить этот метод без static, программа требует экземпляр? Как сделать этот экземпляр?Если через new Program(), то что будет с void Main?

Потому что из статических методов без указания экземпляра можно вызывать только статические методы. Причина этому -- в экземплярные методы неявно передается ссылка на экземпляр объекта, у которого вызывается этот метод (в случае вызова статического метода этой ссылки нет).

В самом простом случае вы действительно можете сделать `Recursive` экземплярным и создавать экземпляр `Program`. С методом `Main` ничего не будет.

```
namespace somenamespace
{
  class Program
  {
    private int value = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var p = new Program();
        p.Recursive(...);
        Console.WriteLine(p.value);
    }

    void Recursive(...)
    {
        value++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А можете объяснить для `ref` и `out` - применимы ли они в данном случае?

Comment: @e1s теоретически вы можете использовать `ref`, но это будет "чересчур". Обычно, если нужно менять значение переменной, заводят поле. `out` не поможет, т.к. вам нужно иметь значение для всех вызовов, а `out` будет "сбрасывать" его после каждого вызова.

Comment: А чего всех тянет global state менять? Чем аргументы метода не угодили?

Answer (score 1):

> Как поступить в таком случае?

Вы можете объявить статическое поле класса `Program`.
Например, так:

```
class Program
{
    static int myField;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Recursive(...)
    }

    static void Recursie(...)
    {
        // тут доступно поле myField
    }
}
```

---

> Почему если объявить этот метод без `static`, программа требует экземпляр?

Ответ: по определению. На бытовом уровне я могу сформулировать это так:

- Обращение к статическим методам осуществляется по имени типа. Пример:

  ```
  string s = "...";
  bool b = String.IsNullOrEmpty(s); // <- вызов статического метода `String.IsNullOrEmpty`
  ```
- Обращение к нестатическим методам осуществляется по ссылке на экземпляр типа. Пример:

  ```
  string s = "...";
  string t = s.Trim(); // <- вызов нестатического метода для экземпляра `s`
  ```

---

> Как сделать этот экземпляр?

Экземпляр всегда создается при помощи оператора `new`. Однако в некоторых случаях этот оператор может не фигурировать в коде явно. Например:

```
int i = 0;
string s = "...";
double[] d = { 0.0, 1.0, 1.5 };
```

Список далеко не полный.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему если объявить этот метод без static, программа требует экземпляр?

Нестатический метод требует экземпляр потому что все нестатические методы требуют экземпляр. Даже не знаю как объяснить подробнее. Это примерно как объяснять, почему вода мокрая.

> Как сделать этот экземпляр?

Экземпляры объектов обычно создаются оператором `new`

> Если через new Program(), то что будет с void Main?

А что должно случиться с void Main?

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен с советами, которые предлагают протаскивать состояние через поля.

Подобные побочные эффекты, особенно на уровне типа, а не объекта - это плохо с точки зрения понимания входов/выходво метода.

Ведь классику никто не отменял. Рекурсивный метод обычно протаскивает состояние через аргументы метода. Именно таким образом мы получаем stateful-программирование в ФП.

Тут правда, появляется проблема. Посколкьу в условии говорится, что метод должен возвращать void, то это значит, что он должен либо выводить что-то на экран (или другим образом показывать результат своей работы) или же менять каким-то другим образом состояние внешнего мира (писать что-то в БД, или же, менять статическое поле).

```
static void Recurse(int state)
{
  // Первое граничное условие
  if (state == 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Все, приехали!");
    return;
  }

  // Первый способ сокращения задачи
  if (state < 10)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Recurse. State: {0}", state);
    Recurse(state - 1);
    return;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("state слишком большой! Уменьшаем его на 10!");
  Recurse(state - 10);

}

void Main()
{
    Recurse(25);
}

state слишком большой! Уменьшаем его на 10!
state слишком большой! Уменьшаем его на 10!
Recurse. State: 5
Recurse. State: 4
Recurse. State: 3
Recurse. State: 2
Recurse. State: 1
Все, приехали!
```

Comment: Если мы говорим о ФП, то void-методы практически исключены. Мне кажется, не стоит бояться поменять сигнатуру метода, чтобы он получал state и возвращал новый state.

Comment: Да, в ФП void методов (особенно в чистом) быть вообще не может. Но и таскать поля там, где можно обойтись параметрами - тоже ведь не стоит.

Comment: Угу, я собственно и имел в виду сделать state не полем, а локальной переменной/параметром/возвращаемым значением.